# Elasticsearch: filter by any field

Tags: elasticsearch

I am playing with filters in elasticsearch (we use old version 1.3.1), and I need to filter my search results by any field. With query, this can be done like this:

```
"query": {
  "query_string": {
    "query": "_all:test"
  }
}
```

But filters seems to not work with **_all** statement. What can I do? Would newer elasticsearch version solve my problem?

Thanks in advance!

**PS:** I need to search exact values, so I cannot use queries. There is difference between queries and filters - if you search for `my brown`, then you can expect results like:

`my brown`

`This is my brown dog.`

`someone stolen my brown wallet`

But filter will return only `my brown`, and that is what I need.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to read up a little on the distinction between [queries and filters](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_queries_and_filters.html). What you're doing there is a [query string query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html).

If you do actually want to filter against exact text tokens (read up on [analysis](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/analysis-intro.html) if you don't know what I mean by "tokens"), AND you have your mapping set up such that the [`"_all"` field](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-all-field.html) behaves as you're expecting then try something like this:

```
POST /test_index/_search
{
   "query": {
      "filtered": {
         "filter": {
            "term": {
               "_all": "test"
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

If, on the other hand, you want to allow some analysis (so that `"Test"` is tokenized to `"test"`, for example), you may want this instead:

```
POST /test_index/_search
{
   "query": {
      "match": {
         "_all": "Test"
      }
   }
}
```

Here is some code I used to play around with it:

http://sense.qbox.io/gist/44adf2c2ade8abd6758f0e08ed2e40434850fc1c

Comment: Thank for your advices. However _all field documentation says it is analyzed field, and this is not good for me, because filters work IMHO only with not_analyzed fields. And I cannot use match query, because it doesn't return really exact results - found string is not necessarily same as given search expression.

Comment: Gotcha. Your question wasn't really clear on all these constraints. For one thing, you can set the analyzer on the `_all` field; here is an [example](http://sense.qbox.io/gist/9f897c2a17078a48a8a88b14e9f93a0d83a1c493) using the whitespace tokenizer (it sounds like that might be the right one for your use-case). You could also use a custom "all" field as described [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-all-field.html#custom-all-fields).

Comment: This is exactly what I don't want - when I search for "Test", result is correct, because only record with field2 = "Test" is returned. Bud when I search for "test", elastic returns record with field2 = "this is a test" and this is not right, because strings are not exactly same. I need really exact search results with _all field.

Comment: Exact matching on the `_all` field doesn't make a lot of sense, because it is a concatenation of values from several different fields (which is probably why there's no way to set `"index": "not_analyzed"` on `_all`); it's not clear exactly how those fields would be concatenated, so even if you know the input values you might not be able to predict the exact unanalyzed value of the `_all` field. Anyway, it sounds like you should create a custom field for your use-case, as described in the link I provided above.

Comment: "doesn't make a lot of sense, because it is a concatenation of values" I agree, I have realized that yesterday too. I will go another way, thank you. :-)